# Downloading CSV contents via Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to download CSV contents via PHP script hosted on the server.

This is the jquery code that executes and creates a table:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://mydomaincom/wp-content/uploads/get-csv.php',
            data: null,
            success: function(text) {

                var fields = text.split(/\n/);
                fields.pop(fields.length-1);
       
                var headers = fields[0].split(','), 
                html = '<table>';
                html += '<tr>';
       
                for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i += 1) {
                    html += '<th scope="col">' + headers[i] + '</th>';              
                }
       
                html += '</tr>';           
                var data = fields.slice(1, fields.length);           
                for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j += 1) {
                    var dataFields = data[j].split(',');              
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td>' + dataFields[0] + '</td>';
                    html += '<td><a href="' + dataFields[1] + '">' + dataFields[1] + '</a></td>';
                    html += '<td>' + dataFields[2] + '</td>';
                    html += '</tr>';           
                }
       
                html += '</table>';
                $(html).appendTo('body');                
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Contents of get-csv.php file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$csv = file_get_contents('http://mydomaincom/wp-content/uploads/csv-samples.csv');
echo $csv;
?>
```

Here is the code for button:

```
<!-- Begin Button -->  
<div class="demo">
<input id = "btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Get It"/>
</div>
<!-- End Button -->
```

From browser:
I can access http://mydomaincom/wp-content/uploads/get-csv.php - no issues
I can access http://mysitecom/wp-content/uploads/csv-samples.csv - no issues

When I click on button nothing happens.

Thanks

Comment: Try with console.log() if the click works and then check if you get inside the success callback there. Also check the browser console - there might be errors. Also check the network-activity tab to see if the request is working.

Comment: You might experience some CORS blocking. Check you browser console for messages in this direction.

Comment: is there any event in the network tab of the browser console?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I tried to put together a working snippet where you can possibly see how it works *when it works* ...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
//    url: 'http://mydomaincom/wp-content/uploads/get-csv.php',
//    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', // --> JSON
      url: "https://data.cdc.gov/api/views/45um-c62r/rows.csv",
      data: null,
      success: function (text) {
        var fields = text.split(/\n/);
        fields.pop(fields.length - 1);

        var headers = fields[0].split(','), html = '<table>';
        html += '<tr>';

        for (var i = 0; i < (headers.length,3); i += 1) {
          html += '<th scope="col">' + headers[i] + '</th>';
        }

        html += '</tr>';
        var data = fields.slice(1, fields.length);
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j += 1) {
          var dataFields = data[j].split(',');
          html += '<tr>';
          html += '<td>' + dataFields[0] + '</td>';
          html += '<td><a href="' + dataFields[1] + '">' + dataFields[1] + '</a></td>';
          html += '<td>' + dataFields[2] + '</td>';
          html += '</tr>';
        }

        html += '</table>';
        $(html).appendTo('body');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSubmit">get data</button>
```

After looking around a bit further I did actually find some publicly available CSV data ("Rates of TBI-related Emergency Department Visits, Hospitalizations, and Deaths - United States, 2001 – 2010" from the U.S. Department of Health & Human Services) and I am now using that to demonstrate the AJAX process.

So, your code basically works. It could be simplified of course but that is not the point. I guess that the problems you encounter with your site are probably CORS-related.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I used the same code and it worked this time "without PHP". I am specifying csv url in jquery code. By the way, you can use cv stored at w3schools for your testing. url: 'https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/data.csv',

Comment: Now that I have an existing table defined with dvCSV ID. How do I use above code to append rows and columns in an existing table. Thank you.